# What does keyword `count` mean in data source?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

when reading open-source terraform module [chgangaraju/terraform-aws-cloudfront-s3-website](https://github.com/chgangaraju/terraform-aws-cloudfront-s3-website/blob/e1daf8bd4b1d0544f9280c4fc4071829d44378f7/main.tf#L13), I found they use `count` in Data source. But I didn't find any document about count.

what does it mean in this place?

```
data "aws_acm_certificate" "acm_cert" {
  count    = var.use_default_domain ? 0 : 1
  domain   = coalesce(var.acm_certificate_domain, "*.${var.hosted_zone}")
  provider = aws.aws_cloudfront
  //CloudFront uses certificates from US-EAST-1 region only
  statuses = [
    "ISSUED",
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It means same as for resource. The pattern uses that you have is an [Conditional Expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html):

```
count    = var.use_default_domain ? 0 : 1
```

The expression with `count` are often used for **optional** resources or data sources. Specifically, in your case, if you set `use_default_domain` to `false`, the CloudFront distro created in this TF script will be created with your own, **custom** domain and SSL certificate. For this to happen, the data source `acm_cert` will fetch information about SSL certificate from ACM for your `acm_certificate_domain`.

In contrast, when `use_default_domain` is `true`, you are going to use **default** domain and SSL certificate from CloudFront. For that you don't need to have any SSL certificate in ACM. Subsequently, TF will not fetch it.

Technically, if `use_default_domain` is `true`, then `count` is `0` and the `data "aws_acm_certificate" "acm_cert"` is **not executed**. But, if `count` is `1` (when `use_default_domain` is `false`), the data source will run and try to fetch information about your custom SSL certificate.

Comment: for resources, `count` determines how many resources to `create`.

Comment: for data source, `count` determines how many resources to `fetch`.

Comment: @RyanLyu Yes, because data sources get info about existing resources. So your SSL cert must already exist.

Answer (score 0):

A data source is a query, which is used for getting data from the outside world and making it available to your Terraform configuration

#### terraform example code

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}


data "aws_ami" "example" {
  count = 2 // look at this line!
  most_recent = true
  owners = ["self"]
}

output "amis" {
  value = "${data.aws_ami.example.*.id}"
}
```

when you specify the count in the data source block, it's similar to SQL `limit`. This can be thought of as equivalent to the following SQL query:

```sql
select * from data_source 
where owners in ('self') 
order by most_recent desc 
limit 2; /** <= look at this line! **/
```

#### Response

The data source returns two records and sends them to the output.

You will see the following results in your terminal.

```
amis = [
  "ami-0345c0186ced78ce6",
  "ami-0345c0186ced78ce6",
]
```

#### Terraform Documentation: [Multiple Resource Instances](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/data-sources/index.html)

> Data resources support `count` and `for_each` meta-arguments as defined for managed resources, with the same syntax and behavior.
>
> As with managed resources, when `count` or `for_each` is present it is important to distinguish the resource itself from the multiple resource instances it creates. Each instance will separately read from its data source with its own variant of the constraint arguments, producing an indexed result.

#### Related Question

- [How can I output a data source that uses count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53585084/how-can-i-output-a-data-source-that-uses-count)